# Convergence's analysis Newton method on special function $f(x) = x/(x^{2} + 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

So I am trying to study the convergence analysis of this function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^{2} + 1}$ with Newton-Ralphson method. I expect the root to be $x =0$. However, when applying Newton numerically (I use matlab) the method actually does not converge. The error for each iteration is quite large. I checked $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$. These functions are continuously differentiable in the domain, and also $f'(x) \neq 0$ for an interval that containing $x = 0$. Is there something that contradicts the convergence property of Newton's method? How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe there's an error in your implementation. In fact, the method converges cubically to $x=0$ in this case, since $f''(0)=0$. Of course, that happens only if the start value $x_0$ is not too far from $0$. In this case, you need $|x_0|<\sqrt{\frac13}$.

Comment: I see. I do not think there is an error in my implementation. I think it is because I choose the initial guess to be $x_0 = 0.75$.

Comment: In that case you "converge" toward the "root" at infinity. Similar to applying the Newton method to $f(x)=e^{-x}$, in both situations the function is convex and falling asymptotically to zero (in some region $[a,\infty)$).

Comment: You shouldn't pick initial points without a reasonable understanding of the function to gain convergence. Usually convexity is sufficient, but your function is not convex near the root. Without an analysis to derive $|x_0|<1/\sqrt3$ to be the bounds, you may also use bracketing to guarantee the existence of the root. See [Newt-safe](https://youtu.be/FD3BPTMGJds?list=PLb0Tx2oJWuYIpNE23qYHGQD42TIR3ThNz), which will allow you to converge even with initial estimates such as $[-5,10]$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Professor Vector commented, you must start with $|x_0]< \frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$.

Suppose that we choose
$$x_0^{(n)}=\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}-10^{-n}$$ and that we count the number of required iterations to have $|x|<10^{-6}$. Here are the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \text{number of iterations} \\
 1 & 4 \\
 2 & 6 \\
 3 & 7 \\
 4 & 9 \\
 5 & 11 \\
 6 & 12 \\
 7 & 14 \\
 8 & 16 \\
 9 & 17 \\
 10 & 19
\end{array}
\right)$$